# Function fired onclick table row, need stop checkboxes from initiating functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, checkbox

I have a function set up to fire when certain table rows are clicked, but here is the general idea:

```
<p onclick="alert('Hello World!');">xxxxxxxxx<input type="checkbox"></p>
```

How do I make it so that function does not fire when a checkbox is clicked?

Comment: apply the onclick event on <input type="checkbox"> and hope it works

Comment: what? He clearly wants it to work when is NOT clicking the checkbox

Comment: I already tried doing the first and third suggested methods before on this page and neither worked. I tried implementing the second suggestion and it also didn't work. I think since the checkbox is a part of the container that it registers it as a click. But there must be some clean workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any case, you must create a click handler for the checkbox.

If you're using jQuery, you only have to call `event.stopPropagation()` in it.

Otherwise, check this post http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html#link9 for a code example (and complete explanation on how bubbling/capturing works).

Comment: If you are **not** using jQuery, be sure to stop it for IE as well manually (see the link)

Then again, these days there is no reason not to use jQuery :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<p onclick="var c = event.srcElement ? event.srcElement : event.target; if(c.tagName === 'P')alert('Hello World!');">Whats up<input onClick="" type="checkbox"></p>
```

With event.srcElement you can access the element that actually triggered the event

EDIT: Firefox doesn't have the property srcElement so it needs to use the target property

Comment: Couldn't you compare `srcElement` to `this`?

Comment: I just tried this in chrome and it worked. I guess it's not Firefox compatible.

Comment: event is not always passed in FF unless it is explicitly passed. You could use this. <p onclick="if(this.tagName === 'P')alert('Hello World!');">xxxxxx<input type="checkbox"></p>

Comment: Nop, the problem is that srcElement property doesnt exist in firefox; just need the target property. Fixed now.

Comment: Using this is much better <p onclick="if(this.tagName === 'P')alert('Hello World!');">xxxxxx<input type="checkbox"></p>

Comment: Wrong, "this" always refers to the object that haves the event assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Easier way is to set up and `.click` event handler for the checkbox and do a [event.stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

$(':checkbox').click (function(event) { event.stopImmediatePropagation(); };

Answer (score 0):

Ivan's answer (+1) works in my test, but if your use case is more complex (that is, clicking child nodes in the P), it could fail.  Another option is:

```
<p onclick="alert('Hello World!');">xxxxxxxxx<input type="checkbox" onclick="event.stopPropagation()"></p>
```

... which works at least in my test (Chrome)